# What are differences between UDP and WCF in SOAP?

Tags: c#, .net

I am now working on a client-server communication project. I implemented the server using UDP client method by simply passing text strings between client and server. But I would like to change it to WCF method. I did some research online about WCF but still cannot figure out what are the difference between WCF and UDP. Need some explanation about it.

Comment: UDP and WCF are very different parts of distributed software. UDP is a low level network protocol for sending chunks of data in a way where order, and delivery are not guaranteed and the software using the network connection has to provide handling for errors in packet delivery. WCF is a library for implementing web service clients and servers using a variety of formats and transport protocols (UDP would be an example of a transport protocol). Unfortunately this kind of "what is the difference between Apples and Oranges" aren't really appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to compare two different concepts. Per the Microsoft web site,

> Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) is a framework for building
>   service-oriented applications.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf

WCF supports a variety of formats - not just SOAP. WCF also supports a variety of transports - one of which is UDP.

The answer to your question is WCF is a client-server communication framework that supports, among many other things, SOAP using UDP.